# Openings with Black

Tags: opening

Can you play openings like Evan’s Gambit or London with black or does that only apply to white?  Or is it better to just react to whites opening? Would love to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Welcome to [chess.se]! Please read the Help Center article [ask]; unfortunately, this question falls short of many Stack Exchange standards.

Answer (score 2):

The London reversed seems possible, although White has to cooperate. It seems difficult to pull off after, for example, 1.d5 d5 2.c4, which is very common.

The Evan's gambit reversed seems quite rare. White doesn't often play the moves that would make it possible. After 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3, Black needs to do something about the hanging pawn, but I think Nc6 or d6 make the gambit a bad idea (Nc6 makes c6 impossible, and d6 means you're wasting a tempo if you want to play d5 - you *really* don't want to waste a tempo when you're sacrificing a pawn for tempo *and* playing a tempo down already due to playing Black.) But I did manage to find one game where Black tried something like an Evans reversed, and won.

```
[Site "London (England)"]
[Date "1846.??.??"]
[White "John W Schulten"]
[Black "Bernhard Horwitz"]
[Result "0-1"]
[StartPly "6"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e5 2. Bc4 Nf6 3. Nc3 b5 4. Bxb5 Bc5 5. d3 c6 6. Bc4 Qb6 7. Qe2 d5 8. exd5 O-O 9. Ne4 Nxe4 10. dxe4 Bxf2+ 11. Qxf2 Qb4+ 12. Bd2 Qxc4 13. Qf3 f5 14. exf5 Bxf5 15. Qb3 Qf1+ 16. Kxf1 Bd3+ 17. Ke1 Rf1# 0-1
```